# Prove that $\tau=\{ \mathbb{R},\emptyset\} \cup \{(-t,t)|t\in\mathbb{I}^+\}$,is not a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $\tau=\{ \mathbb{R},\emptyset\} \cup \{(-t,t) \,\, | \,\, t\in\mathbb{I}^+\}$ is not a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{I}^+$ denotes the positive irrational numbers.

Any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: Have you checked each axiom of the definition of a topology?

Comment: I have done a similar problem, but $t$ was a positive rational number. I have proven that an infinite union of those sets was $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.That's why I think there is a similar way to solve this problem, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? At first it looked to me that you meant: pick one particular positive irrational number $t$ and define $\tau = \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset, (-t,t)\}$. But now from your latest comment I'm not so sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and I added a few small edits if that's okay.

Comment: Thank you, English is not my native language, especially using mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your topology is $\tau = \{ \mathbb R , \emptyset \} \cup \{ (-t,t) : t \in \mathbb Q^c_+ \}$

Let $t_n$ be an increasing sequence of positive irrational numbers converging to a rational number, say $a$. (You should find such a sequence)

Then it is easy to see that although $(-t_n \ ,t_n)$ is in your topology for each $n \in \mathbb N$, the union

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-t_n \ , t_n )$$ equals to $(-a,a)$ which, clearly, is not in your topology.

So, actually the only thing you have to do is to find such sequence $t_n$.

Comment: Easier said, than done. All the sequences I come up with are decreasing...

Comment: Just take $t_n = 5 - \frac \pi n$

Comment: That's it, I just needed to add the -. Thank you a lot.